# Nodemailer and Outlook failing to send a message

Tags: node.js, express, mern, nodemailer

While working on a [MERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack#Examples) application, I decided to create a "Forgot Password" functionality. This is done by making a sendEmail utility and two functions in the *userController.js* file found in the backend. The whole thing seems to be working fine as both [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) and Visual Studio Code returns success statements.

Visual Studio Code terminal message:

````
Token not found. A new token will be created and saved.
Email sent successfully: 250 2.0.0 OK <AM0P193MB057895C2FF6638858F9278AAC5BAA@AM0P193MB0578.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM> [Hostname=AM0P193MB0578.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]```
````

Postman message:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Email sent successfully."
}
```

But in my Outlook inbox, it says the following:

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

capof79562@eachart.com
Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.
```

I have been searching for solutions through the Internet and trying using AI, but nothing was solved. How should I tackle this problem?